# The difference between a Z-Score and a Z-statistic? Why do we divide by $\sqrt{n}$ for the latter?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Trying to understand statistics/hypothesis testing. The example in the book discusses using a Z-Test. I am familiar with and on an intuitive level, I understand a Z-score, a Z-score basically measures how many standard deviations from the mean a point in a sample space is. This makes sense to me.

What I do not understand is why for a Z-test, we seemingly take the Z-score and divide it by $\sqrt{n}$ ?

Can anyone explain the difference, it seems like we are moving away from the intuitive explanation of "number of standard deviations from the mean" which is how we measure the probability via the area under the curve

Answer (score 2):

The key here is that for a sample of $n$ variables $X_i$ with mean $E(X_i)=\mu$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X_i)=\sigma^2,$ the sample mean $\bar X$ has mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}:$  $$ \operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_i \operatorname{Var}(X_i) = \frac{n\sigma^2}{n} = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$ Intuitively as you have more and more observations, the sample mean gets closer and closer to the true mean. So the standard error (i.e. the standard deviation of the sample mean) is $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}.$

Comment: I see, so the formula is the "same", in that the output is still standard deviations from the mean for a given point in our sample, however the formula itself for variance is different because it's a sample? Do I have that correct?

                                                   
Also if you wouldn't mind I'd like to ask one more. When we talk about the law of large numbers and sample sizes, are we saying that we take multiple samples of size N? So if N is 30, we take 50 samples of size N? So we actually survey 1500 people, let's say, instead of just 30? This is has always confused me.

Comment: @user3002540 To the first part, yes. To the second part, usually there is just one sample size. Sometimes in more complicated problems we do consider multiple samples of samples, but it's not the usual case.

Comment: You shouldn't say "more samples", but rather, "more observations" in your sample, or a larger sample size. You're talking about only one sample, with $n$ observations.

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes, maybe that’s part of user’s confusion in the comments here

Answer (score 1):

A z-score is what you get when you subtract its expected value from a random variable and then divide by its standard deviation. Thus if $\operatorname E(X) = \mu$ and $\operatorname{s.d.}(X) = \sigma,$ then the z-score is $\dfrac{X-\mu} \sigma.$

If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ all have expected value $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ and the covariance between any two of them is $0,$ then $\overline X = (X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$ has expected value $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma/\sqrt n.$ Therefore its z-score is $\dfrac{\overline X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt n}.$